# Sequence of Bernoulli Variates with and without Indicator Function

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance

Suppose that $B_{j,n}$ and $C_{j,n}$ are two triangular arrays of iid Bernoulli variates, with each $B_{j,n}$ independent of each $C_{j,n}$ and

$$
\mathbb{P}[B_{j,n}=1]=p,~\mathbb{P}[B_{j,n}=0]=1-p,~\mathbb{P}[C_{j,n}=1]=q,~\mathbb{P}[C_{j,n}=0]=1-q.
$$

I define, recursively, the sequence

$$
\begin{cases}
K_{0,n}&=&0\\ 
K_{j,n}&=& B_{j,n}+B_{j,n}\,K_{j-1,n}
\end{cases}
$$

The integer number $K_{j,n}$ represents the total number of consecutive $B_{q,n}=1$ with $q\leq j$. Similarly I define

$$
\begin{cases}
Q_{0,n}&=&0\\ 
Q_{j,n}&=& C_{j,n}+C_{j,n}\,Q_{j-1,n}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to prove that, for given $j$ and $k$,

$$
0\leq \text{cov}(K_{j,n}\,\mathbb{I}\left\{K_{j,n}\leq Q_{j,n}\right\},K_{j+k,n}\,\mathbb{I}\left\{K_{j+k,n}\leq Q_{j+k,n}\right\})\leq \text{cov}(K_{j,n},K_{j+k,n}\,)\quad(1)
$$

where $\mathbb{I}\left\{\cdot\right\}$ is the indicator function. Below I report some preliminary computations, however they do not seem to help me very much in proving (1) (which I verified via simulations). Is there maybe a simple argument using some property of the indicator function?

**Some attemps** First note that

$$
K_{j,n} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ with probability }1-p\\
1  & \text{ with probability }(1-p)\,p\\
2  & \text{ with probability }(1-p)\,p^2\\
\vdots & \vdots \\
j-1  & \text{ with probability }(1-p)\,p^{j-1}\\
j  & \text{ with probability }p^j
\end{cases}.
$$
and similarly for $Q_{j,n}$. 
Hence

$$
\mathbb{E}[K_{j,n}] = 0\,\cdot (1-p)+1\,(1-p)\,p+2\,(1-p)\,p^2+...+(j-1)\,(1-p)\,p^{j-1}+j\,p^{j}=\frac{p \left(1-p^j\right)}{1-p}
$$
and similarly 
$$
\mathbb{E}[K_{j,n}^2]=\frac{p\, \left(1+p-(2 j (1-p)+1+p) p^j\right)}{(1-p)^2}
$$

whence

\begin{array}
\mathbb{E}[K_{j+k,n}\,K_{j,n}] &=& \mathbb{E}[\left(B_{j+k,n}+B_{j+k,n}\,B_{j+k-1,n}+...+B_{j+k,n}\,B_{j+k-1,n}\,\cdots B_{j+1,n}K_{j,n}\right)\,K_{j,n}] \\
&=& \mathbb{E}[K_{j,n}]\,p\,\frac{1-p^{k-1}}{1-p}+p^{k}\,\mathbb{E}[K_{j,n}^2]
\end{array}

so that

$$
\text{cov}(K_{j,n},K_{j+k,n}) = p\,\frac{\left(1-p^{2 j}-2 j \,(1-p) p^{j-1}\right)\,p^{k+1}}{(1-p)^2}
$$

Now consider that

\begin{array}
\mathbb{E}[K_{j,n}\,\mathbb{I}\left\{K_{j,n}\leq Q_{j,n}\right\}]& = &\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[K_{j,n}\,\mathbb{I}\left\{K_{j,n}\leq Q_{j,n}\right\}]|K_{j,n}] \\ 
&=&\mathbb{E}[K_{j,n}\,\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}\left\{K_{j,n}\leq Q_{j,n}\right\}]|K_{j,n}]\\
&=&\frac{p \left(p^j q^j (j (q-1) (p q-1)+(p-1) q)-p q+q\right)}{(p q-1)^2}
\end{array}